# How to unit test a C function with a FILE* argument

Tags: c, unit-testing, file-io

I have a C function `uint8_t command_read(const FILE* const in)` that reads from `in`.  I would like to write a unit test for the function.  Is it possible to create a `FILE*` in memory for the test since I would like to avoid having to interact with the filesystem?  If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a FILE* in memory for the test?

Sure. For writing:

```
char *buf;
size_t sz;
FILE *f = open_memstream(&buf, &sz);

// do stuff with `f`

fclose(f);
// here you can access the contents of `f` using `buf` and `sz`

free(buf); // when done
```

This is POSIX. [Docs.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html)

For reading:

```
char buf[] = "Hello world! This is not a file, it just pretends to be one.";
FILE *f = fmemopen(buf, sizeof(buf), "r");
// read from `f`, then
fclose(f);
```

[This is POSIX too.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html)

**Sidenote:**

> I'd like to avoid the test having to interact with the filesystem.

Why?

Comment: "*Why?*" - that's the nature of unit testing. You want to test **your module functionality** without the involvement of external factors. That's why external interfaces are usually emulated by stubs or something of a kind.

Comment: @icepack Euh, isn't that sort of unrealistic? I mean, if there's a failure in opening a file, yet the unit test passes...

Comment: UT should inject all possible kinds of inputs into the checked module. Failed file opening is easily emulated by providing a NULL handler to the function. The expected behavior should be return with error or assert.

Comment: I have been a bit slow on the uptake (H2CO3). It is our blood that acid thing - It is carbolic.

Comment: @H2CO3 Pardon the sarcasm, but this is a unit test. Who said anything about "realistic" ? Its my only real bitch about them; that they are relied on for validation of expected-correctness of implementation, while the elephant in the room (*integration*) can/will/does impact encompassing correctness *significantly*.

Comment: @WhozCraig OK, OK, I understand... I just thought this whole thing is a bit of an overkill... but if you say it isn't...

Comment: I would prefer to use the OS that is used every day. Just create a temporary file, bung in some contents to do the test then delete it.

Comment: @WhozCraig "realistic" for UT is substitutable with "possible". Not realistic normally will become very realistic if million users run it under million different conditions. That's where UT is most beneficial - hunting down the corner-case bugs. The easy stuff will most likely be found any way.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Please look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid - Might get some insight into my comment

Comment: @EdHeal I have had advanced-level chemistry classes at high school. What's your problem precisely?

Comment: @icepack I (mostly) agree. I've seen too many times multi-million-line projects with thousands of components and tens of thousands of unit tests, where everything "passes", but the *real* integration falls flat on its face. Don't get me wrong. I completely agree with the philosophy that code *must* be tested for correctness (good data, bad data, edge cases, etc) But call a spade a spade. It is the biggest nearly-unaccounted-for fallacy of unit testing. It has its place. It has its *very useful* place. But just because it passes doesn't mean it *works*.

Comment: @WhozCraig of course :) That's why we also have integrations, system tests, regression etc.

Comment: @h2co3 -I had to think (I know that is a rarity) where I saw H2CO3 before - it was biology and the blood.

Comment: @EdHeal Ah, I see :) Sorry for having been dumb... :/

Comment: I have larger-scale tests that will be passing `stdin` to this function.  Thanks for the input ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 I've clarified my question: I want to read from the `FILE`, not write to it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `tmpfile()`. Its behavior will be a lot closer to that of normal files.